# What parts of Lee's "Introduction to Topological Manifolds" are required for differential geometry?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I am wondering which chapters in Lee's "Introduction to Topological Manifolds" are most important for further studies in differential geometry. [Here](https://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ITM/contents.pdf) is the table of contents.

I intended to read through the first four chapters along with chapters 7, 11, 12 and 13 since I am aware that the topics covered in those chapters feature in various differential geometry texts.

1. Can I safely skip the other chapters without negatively impacting my studies of differential geometry?
2. Do chapters 7,11,12 and 13 require any knowledge from the skipped chapters?

Comment: I've read both books (albeit not that thoroughly) and I would say that if you already took a course in topology (e.g. Munkres) you could probably skip "Topological Manifolds" and begin directly with "Smooth Manifolds". In particular, the chapters on covering spaces and homology in "Topological Manifolds" aren't really used at all in "Smooth Manifolds" except for a couple of arguments in the later chapters (17+ or so). The rest of "Topological Manifolds" is basically a normal treatment of topology emphasizing aspects which are usually neglected in a normal course

Comment: (in particular, an emphasis on proper maps and exhaustion by compact sets come to mind). "Topological Manifolds" is also a good elementary introduction to CW complexes (assuming I remember correctly), but the theory of CW complexes isn't used at all in "Smooth Manifolds", although it is useful knowledge for a study of Differential Topology.

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that "Smooth Manifolds" has an appendix covering briefly _all_ of the topology prerequisites for the book -- I don't remember whether the appendix gives explicit references to the corresponding chapters in "Topological Manifolds", but even if not hopefully they are not difficult to infer using the Table of Contents and Index of "Topological Manifolds". Thus, in short, if you are only interested in differential geometry right now, I would recommend skipping "Topological Manifolds" entirely, reading the topology appendix of "Smooth Manifolds", looking up gaps.

Comment: @Chill2Macht : I'm late to the game. But I was wondering which chapters (or topics) of Lee's "Smooth Manifolds"(ISM) use the notions of homotopy & the Fundamental Group? Is this something extensively used in ISM? Or can one learn about Fundamental Groups independently while reading ISM?

Comment: @math-physicist To be honest I don't remember at all (I decided to get my PhD in something besides pure math, none of my colleagues ever knew anything about differential geometry, so I was never able to use it in my research, so I ended up forgetting most of it...) Taking a wild guess in the dark though, probably the appendix is not that helpful for rigorous topology, especially not homotopy theory / fundamental groups (which are arguably more difficult and more of a specialized / standalone field than the homology part of algebraic topology). Most likely only a "hand-wavey" level of

Comment: understanding of fundamental groups / homotopy is probably needed for an introductory differential geometry text anyway. (E.g. why is the fundamental group of a torus different than that of a sphere, maybe basic understanding / definitions of covering spaces, etc.) Honestly I never liked Hatcher or Munkres very much, but they're basically solid references for learning the subject, even if not very helpful for dumb people like me who have little innate intuition or motivation for learning algebraic top. So I guess either take Jack Lee's word that the appendix is sufficient, or use another book.